# List type is not callable

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am doing MIT OCW 6.0001 problem set 4. It tell me that list type is not callable. But I have not assigned the term "list" to any object. Here is my code:

```
import string


    def load_words(file_name):
    
        print("Loading word list from file...")
        inFile = open(file_name, 'r')
        wordlist = []
        for line in inFile:
            wordlist.extend([word.lower() for word in line.split(' ')])
        print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
        return wordlist
    
    def is_word(word_list, word):
    
        word = word.lower()
        word = word.strip(" !@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]|\:;'<>?,./\"")
        return word in word_list
    
    def get_story_string():
        """
        Returns: a story in encrypted text.
        """
        f = open("story.txt", "r")
        story = str(f.read())
        f.close()
        return story
    
    ### END HELPER CODE ###
    
    WORDLIST_FILENAME = 'words.txt'
    
    class Message(object):
        def __init__(self, text):
    
            self.message_text = text
            self.valid_words = load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME)
    
        def get_message_text(self):
    
            return self.message_text
    
        def get_valid_words(self):
    
            word_copy = self.valid_words[:]
            return word_copy
    
        def build_shift_dict(self, bshift):
    
            alphabet_lower = string.ascii_lowercase
            alphabet_upper = string.ascii_uppercase
            alphabet_dict={}
            n=0
            for i in range(26):
                if i+bshift <= 25:
                    alphabet_dict[alphabet_lower[i]] = alphabet_lower[i+bshift]
                    alphabet_dict[alphabet_upper[i]] = alphabet_upper[i+bshift]
                else:
                    alphabet_dict[alphabet_lower[i]]=alphabet_lower[n]
                    alphabet_dict[alphabet_upper[i]]=alphabet_upper[n]
                    n+=1       
            return alphabet_dict
    
        def apply_shift(self, shift):
    
            alphabet_dictio = self.build_shift_dict(self.get_shift())
            alphabet_keys= alphabet_dictio.keys()
            enc_msg_list = []
            for char in self.message_text:
                if char in alphabet_keys:
                    beta = alphabet_dictio[char]
                    enc_msg_list.append(beta)
                else:
                    enc_msg_list.append(char)
            enc_message_string =""
            for t in enc_msg_list:
                enc_message_string+=t
            return enc_message_string
class CiphertextMessage(Message):
    def __init__(self, text):
        '''
        Initializes a CiphertextMessage object
                
        text (string): the message's text

        a CiphertextMessage object has two attributes:
            self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
            self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words)
        '''
        self.message_text = text
        self.valid_words = load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME)

    def decrypt_message(self):
        '''
        Decrypt self.message_text by trying every possible shift value
        and find the "best" one. We will define "best" as the shift that
        creates the maximum number of real words when we use apply_shift(shift)
        on the message text. 

        Note: if multiple shifts are equally good such that they all create 
        the maximum number of valid words, you may choose any of those shifts 
        (and their corresponding decrypted messages) to return

        Returns: a tuple of the best shift value used to decrypt the message
        and the decrypted message text using that shift value
        '''
```

word_list = self.valid_words()

**THIS IS THE ERROR LINE**

```
encr_msg_list = self.message_text.split()
        c=0
        pala =""
        for dec_key in range(26):
            attempt_dict = self.build_shift_dict(dec_key)
            givenlist1 = attempt_dict.values()
            givenlist=[]
            for owmwo in givenlist1:
                givenlist.append(owmwo)

            correctlist1 = attempt_dict.keys()
            correctlist =[]
            for wop in correctlist1:
                correctlist.append(wop)
            oompa =[]
            n=0
            for elem1 in encr_msg_list:
                word = ""
                for char in elem1:
                    if char in string.ascii_letters:
                        poop = givenlist.index(char)
                        poop1 = correctlist[poop]
                        word+= poop1
                    else:
                        word+= char
                oompa.append(word)
                if word in is_word(word_list, word):
                    n+=1
            if n > c:
                c = dec_key
                for words1 in oompa:
                    pala += word + " "
        return (dec_key, pala)
class PlaintextMessage(Message):
    def __init__(self, text, shift):
        '''
        Initializes a PlaintextMessage object        
        
        text (string): the message's text
        shift (integer): the shift associated with this message

        A PlaintextMessage object inherits from Message and has five attributes:
            self.message_text (string, determined by input text)
            self.valid_words (list, determined using helper function load_words)
            self.shift (integer, determined by input shift)
            self.encryption_dict (dictionary, built using shift)
            self.message_text_encrypted (string, created using shift)

        '''
        self.message_text = text
        self.shift = int(shift)
        self.encryption_dict = self.build_shift_dict(self.get_shift())
        self.message_text_encrypted = self.apply_shift(self.get_shift())

        

    def get_shift(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access self.shift outside of the class
        
        Returns: self.shift
        '''
        return int(self.shift)

        def get_encryption_dict(self):
            '''
            Used to safely access a copy self.encryption_dict outside of the class
        
        Returns: a COPY of self.encryption_dict
        '''
        # boom = self.get_shift()
        shifted_dict = self.build_shift_dict(self.get_shift())
        shifted_dict1 = shifted_dict.copy()
        return shifted_dict1
        

    def get_message_text_encrypted(self):

        return self.message_text_encrypted

    def change_shift(self, shift):

        self.shift = shift
        self.message_text_encrypted = self.apply_shift(self.get_shift())
```

I have looked for all occurrences of using "list" as a variable in the code and I havent done that. I looked up past answers and all said that list type not callable happens when list has been used as a variable which I haven't done. I've been at it for hours now and haven't been able to resolve it. I've highlighted the line where the console gives an error. What is going wrong ? I've also had to define self.valid_words in the sub-class CipherText as the code is not inheriting that from the parent class Message. Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
    
        self.message_text = text
        self.valid_words = ['apple','banana','orange']

message1 = Message("hello")
```

This following generates an error because `valid_words` is an attribute of class Message and by adding the parentheses you are trying to call the list like a function. This generates the following error, as you mentioned:

```
words = message1.valid_words()
print(words)
output: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

To fix this just remove the parenthesis like this:

```
words = message1.valid_words
print(words)
output: ['apple','banana','orange']
```

You can read more about Objects in Python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Edit: Response to inheritance question

In your CiphertextMessage class, you are rewriting the constructor from message. You don't have to do that if they are the exact same. Instead just use the `super()` function to access the constructor from the parent class. Like this,

```
class CiphertextMessage(Message):
  def __init__(self, text):
    super().__init__(text)
```

Alternatively you can explicitly use the Message constructor like this:

```
class CiphertextMessage(Message):
  def __init__(self, text):
    Message.__init__(self, text)
```

You can read up on Python Inheritance [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp).

Comment: @fr4nco Thank you so much for this. I was using stuff in the console and there brackets were needed. Could you also please tell me why the sub-classes aren't inheriting the def __init__ methods from the parent class ? When i tried doing Cipertext.valid_word it tells me that valid word is not an attribute of cipertext subclass

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal I updated my answer to explain.